# Is it normal to have a hidden file named .file in /?

Tags: macos, invisible-files

I searched google and found a list of hidden directories and files in OS X at http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/invisibles.html
but .file wasn't listed.  The file is 0 size and looks like this

```
----------   1 root  admin        0 Aug 24  2013 .file
```

very suspicious?

Running McAfee virus scan there were over 700 additional files that were Not Scanned because they were protected.

- /private/var
- /private/etc
- /Library/Caches
- /Library/Application Support
  and others

Comment: I have `.file` as well, dating January 31st. May be just a leftover from an installer.

Comment: Do not spend money on useless anti virus hoaxware.

Comment: I have .file as well on my Mac (running El Capitan) and my 2 jailbroken devices running iOS 6.1 and iOS 9.

Comment: Side question: is it possible for an empty file to be malicious?

Answer (score 10):

You can query the package receipt database.

```
pkgutil --file-info /.file
```

on a machine running OS X 10.6 the results are

```
volume: /
path: /.file

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem
pkg-version: 10.6.0.1.1.1249291854
install-time: 1252683091
uid: 0
gid: 80
mode: 0

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Essentials
pkg-version: 10.6.0.1.1.1249291854
install-time: 1252683099
uid: 0
gid: 80
mode: 0
```

Comment: FWIW, in the current release of MacOS (Ventura), all I got were `volume` and `path` using both `sudo pkginfo` and `pkginfo`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's normal (and, as others have said, part of the standard OS installation).
It facilitates a natty Apple feature whereby files can be referenced by a composite key of device ID and inode ID, like this: `/.file/id=6571367.17424234/`
Every file and folder in your filesystem can be accessed via this alternate path.
One benefit of this 'reference' path is that it will not change when you rename a file (because the inode ID doesn't change when you rename a file).  I think it's a fundamental part of how aliasing works on a Mac.

Don't remove it.

See 'file reference URL' in [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html).

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's normal and the `.file` file is part of the **BaseSystemResources.pkg** and **Essentials.pkg** packages within the **InstallESD.dmg** disk image of the **Install OS X $version.app** bundle, e.g. **Install OS X Mountain Lion.app**, however I do not know its purpose.

[image]